# Storing variables from queries in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, variables

I have a stored procedure with a username parameter. I want to use one query to grab a userid, then use this variable in further queries.

Here's what I have so far. It compiles OK, but on execution I get an error *"Error converting data type varchar to uniqueidentifier."*

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_User_delete]
    @username uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @UserId uniqueidentifier;

    -- I guess I need to do something here to convert the ID
    SET @UserId = 
        (SELECT UserId FROM aspnet_Users WHERE UserName=@username);

    SELECT * FROM dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles WHERE UserId=@UserId;
END
```

Comment: you can not just convert any string to a uniqueidentifier.  it appears that aspnet_Users.UserId is just such a string.  The T-SQL CONVERT command can convert items, but if the UserId is not a valid uniqueidentifier, there isn't much you can do.  You need to reevaluate what you are doing and make some changes there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-- Proper way to set a variable, will only work properly if one row is returned
SELECT @UserId = UserId 
FROM aspnet_Users 
WHERE UserName = @username
```

Also, if UserId on the aspnet_Users table isn't a UniqueIdentifier you will get the error you describe in your post.

**UPDATE**

After double checking the OP's code I realized that the error isn't in the variable assignment, it's in the WHERE clause.

The UserName field in the aspnet_Users table is probably VARCHAR and the @username param for the SP is uniqueidentifier.

Try changing @username to varchar and see if the statement works.

Comment: I tried that but I still get the same message. The `UserId` field from `aspnet_Users` is definitely `uniqueidentifier`.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat - After double checking your code...you're passing @username in as a UniqueIdentifier. My guess is the UserName field in the aspnet_Users table is varchar (hence the error).

Comment: You're right, it was the `@username` parameter causing the problem. Thanks for the help and better SP syntax :)

Answer (score 4):

This is just going off my gut, but is the UserName column really a uniqueidentifier? It seems like that would normally be a varchar, so the problem may be the type of your @username parameter...maybe that should be varchar as well.

Answer (score 1):

What is the datatype of UserId in aspnet_users?

You can combine your SET/SELECT into a single statement by the way:

```
SELECT @UserId = UserId FROM aspnet_Users WHERE UserName = @username;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the `aspnet_Users.UserId` data type is `uniqueidentifier`?

Your query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles uir
  JOIN aspnet_Users au ON au.userid = uir.userid
 WHERE au.UserName = @username
```

There's no need for passing the variable handling.